# Configurating man page to work like "man xxx"

Tags: 12.04, configuration, c, manpage

I made a application in C. I wrote a manpage for this program and it's called something like edit.1. I "compiled"

```
groff -man -Tascii edit.1 | less
```

Now I can start it like `man ./edit.1` from the main project file of the application but I want to start it like

```
man edit
```

I know that I just could put it into `usr/local/share/man/man1` but the program will be used by many users who re installing the program on their own system. How can I set it up that every user can just input man edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since by default /usr/local/share/man/ is in the MANPATH (see /etc/manpath.config), all users will be able to see it if you put it in that directory. However, do compress it first:

```
gzip edit.1
```

Also, there is already one man page called "edit" (redirected to run-mailcap). This will not be a problem, since /usr/local/share/man takes precedence AFAIR, but you might want to call your program something else.

Comment: sorry... explained it maybe confusing... it s not the users sharing the same pc which means they have to install it by themself... so at the first they will start the make and they can use the application... but make just spawns the execution file ... my question was how could man be automatically put in the directory above or if there is a other way just to call man xxx

Comment: Uh, just configure make to install your files. See the [tutorial here](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_tutorial.html). Create an install target, and put commands to copy (i) your executable and (ii) your man page. However that is a question for another forum.

Comment: it works like putting in makefile the shell command mv editnew.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/editnew.1 but this is dirty I guess... but anyway it works... if there is anyone to say what I have done is totally crab plse tell me also the reason as I am willing to learn

Comment: No, it's not dirty, this is precisely the way it is being done.